# bootstrap form-inline styling not touching

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your comments" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

The issue I am facing is that these two elements aren't taking the entire line (they aren't touching). See here:

[image]

Why is this the case?

Here is a fiddle show casing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/nirchernia/pyfetd4p/

Comment: What is the meaning of *"aren't taking the entire line (they aren't touching)"*

Comment: I'd like for the <input> to extend all the way to the <button>

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- form-group is display:block.
- put both the input and button tag inside the same form-group
- The form-control is a display:block as well.  Use CSS to force it to display:inline-block and shorten the width (it was 100%).

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6x12fc8/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your comments" /> 
    <button class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
</div>

.form-inline .form-control { width:75%; display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Even with `inline-block` the button will be slightly padded from the input, due to inline elements being treated like "words" and thus having the whitespace in the markup being rendered. This can be dealt with by setting the parent element's `font-size` to 0. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pyfetd4p/4/

Comment: Another fix is to float:left the input and the button.  The form-group div would have to be clearfixed.

Answer (score 0):

Give following css. Because currently it will taking `width:auto;` So, it will take default width of input field.

To make it touch with button. Give `100%`  and there is padding given so, it will increase more width and overlap the button. So, remove padding but `padding:0`

```
.form-inline .form-control {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pyfetd4p/1/

To make side by side in small screen use following css;

```
.form-inline {
    display: flex;
}
```

**[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pyfetd4p/3/)**

Comment: he was missing an } at the end :D !

Comment: @user3284463 what issue you are facing?

Comment: The button is underneath the comment box

Comment: In this https://jsfiddle.net/pyfetd4p/2/ it works but I'm not sure of using `display:flex;` on `.form-inline`

Comment: @user3284463 Yeah. That will do the trick. But different way. Check my edited answer.